# component return white blank screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to check if the user authorised the use of the camera and location and if he did not, then a simple screen should be render that let him know about it. The function getting invoked but the return statement return blank screen instead of the component.

NOTE : 
I tried to use 'backgroundColor: 'black' ti see if the  rendered and I can't even see the black background.

CODE:

```
 componentWillMount() {
  Permissions.checkMultiple(['camera', 'location']).then(response => {
    //response is an object mapping type to permission
      console.log('permission check')
      console.log('response.camera', response.camera)
      console.log('response.location', response.location)
      if (response.camera === 'denied' || response.location === 'denied') {
        return (

          <View>

          <Text>
              Sorry you cant use this app without allowing Location and Camera permmision
              to do it just go to Setting/Keepr and allow Location and Camera access for this app 
          </Text>

          <Button title={'go to settings'} onPress={Permissions.openSettings}></Button>

          </View>

        )
      }
  })
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to return a JSX in a `componentWillMount`... and inside the Promise callback. This simply won't work as you need to return JSX from `render` method. You can use the react-state to do that. Example:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.state = {
      response: {}
    };
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    Permissions.checkMultiple(["camera", "location"]).then(response => {
      this.setState({ response });
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { response } = this.state;
    if (response.camera === "denied" || response.location === "denied") {
      return (
        <View>
          <Text>
            Sorry you cant use this app without allowing Location and Camera
            permmision to do it just go to Setting/Keepr and allow Location and
            Camera access for this app
          </Text>

          <Button title={"go to settings"} onPress={Permissions.openSettings} />
        </View>
      );
    }
    return <p>something</p>;
  }
}
```